# asp.net mvc3 authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, httpmodule

Is there any solution for redirect user to login page, when cookie expires?

I create `formsauthenticationticket` and cookie. Expiration is set on 10minutes.

When expiration is over, and user doesn't make any request 20-minutes, and after that, 
clicks he on some link, he would be redirected to login page and log in again.

I have `HttpModule` in assembly, which is referenced in web project.

In this module I have `PreRequestHandlerExecute()` event, 
where I control on every request, if the user is authenticated and refresh timeout for cookie.

But If the user is not authenticated, he would be redirect to login page.
Is there any solution for this? I know about `AuthorizeAttribute`, but is there any other way to do this?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Once the user's cookie has expired it won't be sent in the request, so you have no way of knowing who is a new user and who is a user who's cookie has expired because neither user will send a cookie with their page request.

One *workaround* is to set the cookie to 10 mins, but use the [Meta Refresh tag](http://www.pageresource.com/html/metref.htm) to redirect to the login  page after 9 mins 50 seconds. Note: the login page would need to log the user out too, otherwise it would refresh the session again.